# How to use DatarateChannel connection?

Tags: omnet++

I hope you be fine As you see I have created this topology , every device has different .ned file . their input and output element I coded like this

```
inout gate[];
```

In Network.ned File i use below for connection

```
import ned.DatarateChannel;
```

But I got error when I use "C" instead of "DatarateChannel"

```
computer.gate++ <--> C <--> switch11.gate++;
```

So how can I handle it ???

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you forgot to declare `C` channel. Add something like this in your `ned` file:

```
channel C extends ned.DatarateChannel {
    // parameters of this channel, for example:
    datarate = 1Mbps;
}
```

For available parameters of channel look at [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual - Chapter 3.5](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:channels)